# REST API Is it neccessary to check relationship between parent and child when adding child

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

While creating a REST API in Spring Boot, I encountered a doubt. When I have a representation of a resource for example:

```
POST /users/userId/posts/postId/comment
```

I want to add a new comment to user's post. While adding a new comment, do I need to check *if this particular user is the owner of the post* and then add the comment to the post or is it fine if I do it by fetching this post from database by `PostRepository` and then add the comment to post?

Comment: Semantically speaking, yes, a user can be able to comment any post including those that he has not originally authored. Meanwhile, your representation would then break the sub-resource REST representation as in such a case, the *posts* would no more be considered as a *users* sub-resource and a totally independent resource that can exist out of a user context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need it.

You can find/check the post by postId and userId, then add the comment if valid otherwise an exception will be present

Maybe you should check the status of user and that post is allowed leave a comment or not lol